# Formula In Name Manager Displays 1 Short

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula in the excel name manager that is supposed to create a table without blanks. The problem is that it creates a table without the last field which is filled in.

Table Name: Resource_ID
Table Formula:

```
='Failure Codes'!$H$2:INDEX('Failure Codes'!$H:$H,SUMPRODUCT(--('Failure Codes'!$H:$H<>"")))
```

I am wondering why the last cell in the column is not being included and how this can be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that Failure Codes'!$H:$H is text.

```
='Failure Codes'!$H$2:INDEX('Failure Codes'!$H:$H, match("zzz", 'Failure Codes'!$H:$H))
'to discard zero-length strings things get a bit more complicated
='Failure Codes'!$H$2:INDEX('Failure Codes'!$H:$H, AGGREGATE(14, 7, ROW('Failure Codes'!$H$2:INDEX('Failure Codes'!$H:$H, MATCH("zzz", 'Failure Codes'!$H:$H)))/SIGN(LEN('Failure Codes'!$H$2:INDEX('Failure Codes'!$H:$H, MATCH("zzz", 'Failure Codes'!$H:$H)))), 1))
```

If Failure Codes'!$H:$H were numbers then,

```
='Failure Codes'!$H$2:INDEX('Failure Codes'!$H:$H, match(1e99, 'Failure Codes'!$H:$H))
```

If Failure Codes'!$H:$H were a combination of text and numbers then,

```
='Failure Codes'!$H$2:INDEX('Failure Codes'!$H:$H, max(iferror(match(1e99, 'Failure Codes'!$H:$H), 2), iferror(match("zzz", 'Failure Codes'!$H:$H), 2))
```

Don't use full column references with SUMPRODUCT.

`SUMPRODUCT(--('Failure Codes'!$H:$H<>"")` was likely failing due a blank or zero-length string left by a formula.

Comment: Only Text. Thank you for the elaborate explanation. There is one problem. I don't want it to include the cells with "" (blank cells).

Comment: So apparently sometimes there are numbers and letters that populate in the table. So I had to modify your formula to include it all. Thank you for the detailed explanation. The formula I ended up with: `='Failure Codes'!$H$2:INDEX('Failure Codes'!$H:$H, AGGREGATE(14, 7, ROW('Failure Codes'!$H$2:INDEX('Failure Codes'!$H:$H, max(iferror(match(1e99, 'Failure Codes'!$H:$H), 2), iferror(match("zzz", 'Failure Codes'!$H:$H), 2))))/SIGN(LEN('Failure Codes'!$H$2:INDEX('Failure Codes'!$H:$H, max(iferror(match(1e99, 'Failure Codes'!$H:$H), 2), iferror(match("zzz", 'Failure Codes'!$H:$H), 2))))), 1))`

Comment: Glad to hear it worked out for you. Oddly enough, as complicated as that formula is it actually uses many less calculation cycles than your solitary SUMPRODUCT with full column references.